# Get rid of "Nullable" warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have the following code:

```
var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonbytes);
var claims = keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString()));
```

As you can see my ide shows me a Nullable warning.

[image: vscode warning]

I know that I have to check if a variable is null before using it to get rid of such a warning. But I don't know how to do it with dynamic variables in a linq query..?

I hope someone can show me how I can avoid such a warning in this situation.

Comment: maybe either paste the error message as text or paste the image here directly (I understand you may not have permission to do that yet), never post an external image link as it could always be a poisoned link. (and may stop existing in future)

Comment: @Slipoch There was never anything wrong with the image - it was only missing the leading "!" to show it inline

Comment: Huhhh, ok. Thank you for the hint. I was not allowed to upload a image.

Comment: Ahh righteo! awesomesauce, wasn't sure if you had permissions to add images yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The IDE gives you this warning as this variable might be `null` when it hits this line.

If you are fully confident that this will never be the case, you can use the `!` to escape these warnings:

```
keyValuePairs!.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value!.ToString())!);
```

If 1 of the properties might be `null` you can escape these:

```
keyValuePairs?.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value?.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, this works for keyValuePairs object but not for the kvp.value object. The IDE shows always a warning for the value.

Comment: ok, i found the reason why. I have to set the ! on the ToString() method too.

var claims = keyValuePairs!.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key!, kvp.Value!.ToString()!));

Comment: Do note that this does not prevent a NullReferenceException when it in reality still has a `null` value. `kvp.Value?.ToString()` (using `?` instead of `!`) just returns `null` in that case

Answer (score 1):

In your .csproj file, you will find like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` field gonne be disable. I think this is your solution. But not safe one.

Answer (score 0):

as pazcal said already i can use a ! after the object to escape such a warning. Many thanks for that hint.

Anyway, i've changed my function now to this:

```
private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
{
    if (jwt!=null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(jwt)) {
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonbytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonbytes);
        if (keyValuePairs!=null && keyValuePairs.Count > 0) {
            var claims = keyValuePairs!.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key!, kvp.Value!.ToString()!));
            return claims;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error while deserializing jwt json string.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("jwt value cannot be empty or null");
    }            
}
```

I hope, that this is safe now :-)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you decide to write the first null check explicitly, your very first `!.` could be just a `.`. If you want to be fancy, you can write the combined check `keyValuePairs !=null && keyValuePairs.Count > 0` as `keyValuePairs?.Count > 0`. (Also, you can leave out two `else` if you want, since control is not going to leave the `if` part anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var claims = keyValuePairs?.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty));
```

How about this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot I don't understand what is your intention. Are you just a bot? He asked how he can remove the warning in his code. So I just suggest the edited one from my side. I think It does need any extra explanation. That's all.